# Polymer is the View in MVC. What can I use for the Model and Controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, model, controller, polymer

I'm reaching the point where I need well defined models and controllers would be nice to handle server API calls separately from the HTML. It's interesting seeing how [core-ajax](https://github.com/Polymer/core-ajax/blob/master/demo.html) does it though. I can certainly use core-ajax for the server calls, but I am curious as to what other developers use for the model and controller parts that play well with Polymer.

Comment: `core-ajax` is old. Use [`iron-ajax`](https://github.com/polymerelements/iron-ajax) if you go down that route.

Comment: fairpoint, thanks.

Comment: @KayceBasques, is iron-ajax the best way (or the default convention) to do ajax requests using Polymer?

Answer (score 0):

I have a pretty similar scenario here … 
I’ve a set of elements (View) and each one has their own Models and “Controllers” in separated Javascript classes .. 
So … We created an JS Api structure here separated into different packages and .js files and each component has the reference for the .js files that they depends on